# Submit form to other url within Joomla! plugin

Tags: plugin, form

What I'm trying to achieve is auto submit a subscribe form (with specific user details) to my email provider (similar to mailchimp), when a new user register to my joomla site.

I already defined a plugin with an event that triggers when a new user register to my site.

But I'm really not sure how to auto submit a form or a url with the user details.

For example, the following line would do what I need but I don't know how to trigger it from my plugin:

https://cp.responder.co.il/subscribe.php?fields[subscribers_name]=Test&fields[subscribers_email]=test@test.com&form_id=1234&encoding=UTF-8

Any ideas how can I accomplish this would be really appreciated.

Thanks!
Omri

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, a plugin does not usually generate a form. They are mostly oriented for internal processing.

In general, a module is the right place to generate a form. Then, a form have an *action* field were you can define the external Url to submit it. Additionally, you can define a *method*, either *post* or *get* (in your case a *get*). Finally, you can define the form fields to match your requirements.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form

Comment: Thank you. So how do I send the user registration information to other url that handles my auto-responders (like mailchimp). As I wrote, when a user register to my site, I want to send the user info to my auto-resopnder service. I though it would be easier to simulate the form subscribe. Is there another way? Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend to manage your mailing in AcyMailing and integrate a SMTP delivery service like SendGrid, PostMark, or Amazon SNS.

Answer (score 0):

```
$content = http_build_query (array (
            'fields[subscribers_name]' => $user['name'],
            'fields[subscribers_email]' => $user['email'],
            'form_id' => '1234',
            'encoding' => 'UTF-8'
            ));

            $context = stream_context_create (array (
            'http' => array (
            'method' => 'POST',
            'content' => $content,
            )
            ));

            $result = file_get_contents('https://cp.responder.co.il/subscribe.php', null, $context);
```